# Create a trigger that records and updates changes to a table

Tags: sql-server, database, triggers

This is what the exercise is asking:

"Trigger Associated with the Historical table that responds to the Insert, and that must update the status of the Incident and the date of modification"

In other works, create a trigger that record the updates to the incident status and add the date that was modify.

Here is the main the main table that will be reference in the trigger.

```
CREATE TABLE Incident(
   Incident_ID                  INT IDENTITY(1,1)   NOT NULL,
   Incident_status              INT                 NULL,

CONSTRAINT PK_ID_Incident PRIMARY KEY (ID_Incident),
)
```

It does not matter is a new table needs to be created to solve the issue.

Comment: Do your own homework. At the very least, you can write a stub trigger (hint - for insert and for update) that does nothing but will at least compile.

Comment: The MS docs show how to create a trigger... googling `sql server history trigger` will give examples...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a trigger like this here you don't need to put any column name for update tracking it automatically insert column name, old values and new values. Only you have to create a log table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TR_Employee_AUDIT] ON [dbo].[Employee_mstr] FOR UPDATE
AS

DECLARE @bit INT ,
       @field INT ,
       @maxfield INT ,
       @char INT ,
       @fieldname VARCHAR(128) ,
       @TableName VARCHAR(128) ,
       @PKCols VARCHAR(1000) ,
       @sql VARCHAR(2000), 
       @UpdateDate VARCHAR(21) ,
       @UserName VARCHAR(128) ,
       @Type CHAR(1) ,
       @PKSelect VARCHAR(1000),
       @empcode VARCHAR(20)


--You will need to change @TableName to match the table to be audited. 
-- Here we made GUESTS for your example.
SELECT @TableName = 'Employee_Mstr'

-- date and user
SELECT         @UserName = SYSTEM_USER ,
       @UpdateDate = CONVERT (NVARCHAR(30),GETDATE(),126)

-- Action
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted)
       IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted)
               SELECT @Type = 'U'
       ELSE
               SELECT @Type = 'I'
ELSE
       SELECT @Type = 'D'

-- get list of columns
SELECT * INTO #ins FROM inserted
SELECT * INTO #del FROM deleted

select @UserName = EMP_ModifiedBy, @empcode = emp_cd from #ins
if isnull(@UserName,'') = ''
select @UserName = EMP_ModifiedBy, @empcode = emp_cd from #del

-- Get primary key columns for full outer join
SELECT @PKCols = COALESCE(@PKCols + ' and', ' on') 
               + ' i.' + c.COLUMN_NAME + ' = d.' + c.COLUMN_NAME
       FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS pk ,

              INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE c
       WHERE   pk.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
       AND     CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
       AND     c.TABLE_NAME = pk.TABLE_NAME
       AND     c.CONSTRAINT_NAME = pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME

-- Get primary key select for insert
SELECT @PKSelect = COALESCE(@PKSelect+'+','') 
       + '''<' + COLUMN_NAME 
       + '=''+convert(varchar(100),
coalesce(i.' + COLUMN_NAME +',d.' + COLUMN_NAME + '))+''>''' 
       FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS pk ,
               INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE c
       WHERE   pk.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
       AND     CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
       AND     c.TABLE_NAME = pk.TABLE_NAME
       AND     c.CONSTRAINT_NAME = pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME

IF @PKCols IS NULL
BEGIN
       RAISERROR('no PK on table %s', 16, -1, @TableName)
       RETURN
END


SELECT         @field = 0, 
       @maxfield = MAX(ORDINAL_POSITION) 
       FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName
       AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('EMP_ModifiedOn','EMP_ModifiedBy')
WHILE @field < @maxfield
BEGIN
       SELECT @field = MIN(ORDINAL_POSITION) 
               FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
               WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName 
               AND ORDINAL_POSITION > @field
               AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('EMP_ModifiedOn','EMP_ModifiedBy')
       SELECT @bit = (@field - 1 )% 8 + 1
       SELECT @bit = POWER(2,@bit - 1)
       SELECT @char = ((@field - 1) / 8) + 1
       IF SUBSTRING(COLUMNS_UPDATED(),@char, 1) & @bit > 0
                                       OR @Type IN ('I','D')
       BEGIN
               SELECT @fieldname = COLUMN_NAME 
                       FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
                       WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName 
                       AND ORDINAL_POSITION = @field
                       AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('EMP_ModifiedOn','EMP_ModifiedBy')
               SELECT @sql = '
insert NewAuditLog (    Type, 
               TableName, 
               PK, 
               FieldName, 
               OldValue, 
               NewValue, 
               UpdateDate, 
               UserName)
select ''' + @Type + ''',''' 
       + @TableName + ''',''' + @empcode + ''',''' + @fieldname + ''''
       + ',convert(varchar(1000),d.' + @fieldname + ')'
       + ',convert(varchar(1000),i.' + @fieldname + ')'
       + ',''' + @UpdateDate + ''''
       + ',''' + @UserName + ''''
       + ' from #ins i full outer join #del d'
       + @PKCols
       + ' where i.' + @fieldname + ' <> d.' + @fieldname 
       + ' or (i.' + @fieldname + ' is null and  d.'
                                + @fieldname
                                + ' is not null)' 
       + ' or (i.' + @fieldname + ' is not null and  d.' 
                                + @fieldname
                                + ' is null)' 
               EXEC (@sql)
       END
END
```

The output after update will be generated as shown below.

[image]